# Underscore Based Theme File Permissions in Git

Tags: theme-development, security, git

I'm using underscores to develop my theme. For some reason git is saying that my file permissions are being changed from 10644 to 10744. I can override this in git's settings this but is it safe for me to turn off file permission checking in or does underscores need specific file permissions.